# Append custom attribute optionally/manually?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Following this in the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['is_admin'];

    public function getIsAdminAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['admin'] == 'yes';
    }
}
```

Is it possible to manually append my custom attribute in a query?

There are certain situations where I don't need to have this information in my JSON, and I'd rather be able to manually append the custom attribute in a query, like:

```
$users = User::append('is_admin')
    ->get();
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work with the `makeVisible` method, as long as an accessor is defined or the value is in the table.

`$users = User::all()->makeVisible('is_admin')->toArray();`

More information about the method can be found in the doc directly above the linked paragraph.

Comment: So, in other words, I have to set `is_admin` to be hidden by default and then call `makeVisible()` when I want to include it in the JSON?

Comment: @user7733152 Yes, but there is another option. You can include `is_admin` in the `$visible` array, in case you want to include it in every response of that model